# Вызов функции с задержкой

Tags: c++, функции

Всем привет. Использую Visual C++ 2010. Столкнулся с такой проблемой - не могу создать задежку, для вызова функции (мне ее надо вызывать, допустим, раз в минуту).

У меня есть кнопка, я на нее нажимаю, запускается цикл:

```
while(true) {
    ScreenShot (HWND);
}
```

Эту функцию мне надо выполнять, естественно не каждую секунду, а, например, раз в минуту. Sleep(); перед функцией вызывает зависание программы (Ну об этом в гугле  много информации). Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно вызвать задержку выполнения. С SetTimer что-то я так и не разобрался.

Comment: А что у вас за программа? Командная строка? Windows application без UI? UI на чистом WinAPI? MFC? Qt?

Comment: Если в используемом Вами фреймворке есть таймеры, то используйте их. Если нет, то, как вариант, по нажатию на кнопку создавайте отдельный поток и внем делайте вызов `ScreenShot` с задержкой между вызовами

Answer (score 1):

Если программа с окном, то создаете таймер через `SetTimer`, а в оконной функции по сообщению `WM_TIMER` вызываете `ScreenShot (HWND)`;
Второй вариант - вынести указанный Вами код в отдельный поток. Потом убивать его при необходимости.

Answer (score 0):

Для реализации вашей задумки, понадобятся потоки или библиотеки асинхронного исполнения.
Рекомендую посмотреть в сторону `Boost.Thread` и/или `Boost.ASIO`.